# Capturing save and cancel event on window.open() in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, windows-10, dom-events

I am saving a file locally in js like this

```
var win = window.open(appConfig.server_url + '/v1/discussion/files/download/chat' + '/' + params);
```

on browser this opens a new tab and downloads the files and closes the tab, but on electron this opens a file save dialog like shown below:

[image]

So I want to capture the save and cancel event in the js so that on clicking save user should get **"download successful"** message and on cancel nothing should happen.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: while clicking save button this **window.open** is called nothing else is bothering the flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can register listener to `session` to catch `'will-download'` event. In the callback you have access to the current `DownloadItem` and can do whatever you want with it.

Electron [docs example](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/download-item.md):

```
// In the main process.
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
  // Set the save path, making Electron not to prompt a save dialog.
  item.setSavePath('/tmp/save.pdf')

  item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
    if (state === 'interrupted') {
      console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed')
    } else if (state === 'progressing') {
      if (item.isPaused()) {
        console.log('Download is paused')
      } else {
        console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}`)
      }
    }
  })
  item.once('done', (event, state) => {
    if (state === 'completed') {
      console.log('Download successfully')
    } else {
      console.log(`Download failed: ${state}`)
    }
  })
})
```

I hope this helps!